# Union of distinct dense $G_\delta$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $X$ be a separable topological space and let $\left\{X_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ be a non-empty collection of distinct dense $G_{\delta}$ subsets satisfying
$
\cap_{i \in I} X_i
$
is dense in $X$.

Does there exist a finite and [strictly positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_positive_measure) Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ satisfying
$$
\mu\left(
X- 
\cup_{i \in I} X_i
\right)=0
?
$$

Comment: Satisfying what exactly?

Comment: The intersection is dense in $X$.

Comment: If the intersection has a dense sequence $x_n$, then $\mu(A)=\sum_n{2^{-n}1(x_n \in A)}$ works.

Comment: But what is $x_n$ in this case?  Since things may not be countable.